# Grep: Count specific string in all recursive files with matchi filename

Tags: grep

I already could manage to count strings in all files in directory:

```
grep -roh „XXX" . | wc –w
```

But I don't know how to isolate the statement. I only want to count the words in files which have the the following string "2015-09-25" in the filename.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, it uses `find` to isolate the files that you are interested in and then runs grep just on those files:

```
find /mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*2015-09-25*" -execdir grep -roh "XXX" "{}" \+ | wc -w
```

If you want to find files in subdirectories of /mydir as well, just remove `-maxdepth 1`

Answer (score 1):

If all files are on current directory, try

```
grep -oh "XXX" *2015-09-25*
```

else try

```
 grep -roh -c --include="*2015-09-25*" "XXX"
```

where

- `-r` tell grep to recurse
- `--include="*2015-09-25*"` filter on file's basename.